# Java KeyBind-Determining a Key Released Event

Tags: java, event-handling, action, keylistener, keyboard-events

**Short Version:** 
How do I determine when a KeyBind key has been released in similar functionality to a KeyListener keyReleased() event?

**Long Version:**
I am experimenting a bit with making a very simple game, and I was using several KeyListeners to track my keyboard input.  However, as I added more complicated features, I began to encounter issues with the keyboard input not receiving proper focus and thus no keyboard input was being received.

Then I read about KeyBinds.  While the KeyBinds functionality fixed my focus issue, for my game I was wanting to change a value based off whether a key was pressed or not.  I can get the value to change through pressing the key, but I don't know how to detect when the key is released.  The KeyListener had a separate KeyPressed and KeyReleased method, but that won't work correctly due to component focusing issues.

**Relevant Code:** 
I don't have a lot of code to share because the input was simply needed to call one of two methods which are set up in another class (and I was testing KeyBinds).  But here is the relevant KeyBind code anyway:

```
    Action myAction = new AbstractAction()
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            System.out.println("testing action output");

        }

    };
    actionMap = getActionMap();
    inputMap = getInputMap(condition);

    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "leftArrow");
    actionMap.put("leftArrow", myAction);
```

And here's the code I was using with KeyListener (again, very little since I just call a method)

```
addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
            {
                racquetClass.keyPressed(e);
            }
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
            {
                racquetClass.keyReleased(e);
            }
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
            {

            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance to any and all help that can be provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I don't know how to detect when the key is released.

You need to create a separate Key Binding:

```
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "leftArrowReleased");
actionMap.put("leftArrowReleased", myReleasedAction);
```

Comment: Oh wow, you just add "true" to the end?  I feel really dumb now.  Thank you sir :)